# HTTPS : How do I Encrypt _only_ the password _only_ when user is signing in or registering?

Tags: asp.net, security, encryption, ssl, https

Suppose I have a login web form like the following:

**UserId**: testuser

**Password**: ThisIsStrongPwd

[LOGIN] (button)

Now, all I want to do is encrypt the password (using an industry-accepted secure measure) when the user clicks the [LOGIN] button.

I know that SSL will encrypt the entire POST, right?
The steps will be something like:

1. User types id and password.
2. User clicks [LOGIN] button Info is posted securely to web server. --- How?
3. Server-side checks the pwd the user posted against the (hashed) one in the database.
4. Server returns to user their default.aspx page or index.htm page or whatever on an UNencrypted (non-SSL) URL.

There is no need for the rest of the session to be encrypted -- and possibly slow.
How would you do this using ASP.NET for example? or ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: This is fundamentally impossible.

Comment: @SLaks No wonder I cannot find the solution anywhere then.  Someone needs to fix the Interent then. Cuz this the way it should work. :)

Comment: @daylight: No, it shouldn't work that way. There is not much point in sending data securely from an unsecure page.

Comment: HTTPS is a protocol over TCP but below the application level. Application usually has no idea it is working over SSL/TLS once the connection is established. What you want is impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSL is used to encrypt the transport layer, it's not a tool to encrypt specific values. All requests and responses for the page is encrypted, which is the point of having the page secure.

You can only send data securely from a page that is secure. If you would only encrypt data one way, you would be sending the data from an unsecure page. Someone could have intercepted the page and added code to it that steals the password before it's encrypted.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Let me set this up a bit better.  All I want to do is allow a user to login, for example. The only thing that is important to encrypt is the password -- which will then get checked for validity on the server side.  So, what is the best way to encrypt the password to get it across the line so that it can be hashed and placed into the database yet still provide the rest of the pages as non-SSL?  Possible? I appreciate any ideas you provide.

Comment: @daylight: You should rethink that approach. You would be providing something that sounds like it's secure, but is not. Like bullet proof windows on a regular car.

Comment: Good analogy.  I guess I'm not even close to understanding what I want then -- and that is the root issue.  I'm just building a "little app" and I have all the stuff worked out to keep the user's password safe (hash into database on server side) except the part about getting the password across the line -- from the client's browser to the server.  It's got me stumped. I'm probably also breaking convention because it's  a "little app." and all I really want to insure is that no one sees their password. Now I'm thinking, "Okay, time to learn OAuth and let them register / login that way.

Answer (score 2):

> ..all I want to do is encrypt the password (using an industry-accepted secure measure) ..

For your use case, SSL is the only industry-accepted secure measure. There are ways to encrypt and send a form data from the browser without requiring ssl, such as [jCryption](http://www.jcryption.org/). But they are not a replacement for SSL. read this [Javascript Cryptography Considered Harmful](http://www.matasano.com/articles/javascript-cryptography/)

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible in an application where you will accept users you (the server) do not otherwise know. The foundational problem you have is the requirement to share a secret that will enable you to encrypt and decrypt information that no one else can read.

Without a process to negotiate that secret, *you cannot communicate securely*. Negotiating that secret is one of the key features of SSL/TLS.

It will likely be useful to read up on the history and implementation of TLS to understand why it is necessary to have a fully secure channel. You may also be interested to learn about session jacking, a mechanism by which a third-party can "steal" a login token that is exposed outside of an SSL session.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I would like to say this: It is amazing how that one small thing we may want to do as a software developer (encrypt a client-side password) _should be_ so easy but then takes so long since we have to "read up on the history and implementation of TLS..."  6 weeks later I emerge from the wood shed with my TLS/SSL solution after reading half the Internet.  Yes, I'm a fast reader.  :)

Comment: :) Well, you don't need to read up on the history and implementation of TLS to use it, you just need it in order to come with something better.